# Vim won't use default colorscheme

Tags: rhel, vim, colors, vimrc

I was using the default vim colorscheme, and one day when I turned on my computer, suddenly everything was a really weird theme with a red background and yellow/white text (I'm not even sure if this is even a colorscheme?) 
My ~/.vimrc contains `colo evening` but vim files still open with the red colorscheme. How can I fix this?

Comment: The first suspect is the environment variable `TERM`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I've tried setting it to xterm, rxvt, and konsole, all with the same result. :(

Comment: Maybe ask here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/